# Linq query for fetch data based on startdate and enddate

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

my table data is below

Choose team:

```
        fromdate    todate      IsWaiting 
72  54  11/26/2015  11/30/2015  True     
73  54  12/2/2015   12/5/2015   True    
74  54  11/26/2015  11/27/2015  False
```

now I want to fetch date based on **fromdate** and **todate**

suppose

```
  startdate= "2015-12-03";
  enddate= "2015-12-07";
```

OR

```
  startdate= "2015-12-01";
  enddate= "2015-12-07";
```

then i want result only second row

i have tried

```
 from ct in db.ChooseTeams
    where ct.IsWaiting == true &&
           ((startdate>= ct.FromDate && startdate<= ct.ToDate) || (enddate<= ct.ToDate && enddate>= ct.ToDate))                                             select ct
```

and

```
 from ct in db.ChooseTeams
      where ct.IsWaiting == true &&
      ((startdate>= ct.FromDate && enddate<= ct.ToDate) || (dateEnd <= ct.ToDate && enddate >= ct.ToDate))
                                                                               select ct
```

Your help will appreciate . THANX IN ADVANCE

Comment: is there any error occuring?

Comment: var t  = (from ct in db.newTab where (s >= ct.D1 && e <= ct.D2) select ct).ToList(); I have checked

Comment: `enddate<= ct.ToDate && enddate>= ct.ToDate` is equivalent to `enddate==ct.ToDate`. You probably meant to type `startDate<=`. BTW what are the field types? If either the parameters or the fields are strings instead of DateTime, you have a bug

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code:

```
var startdate= DateTime.ParseExact("2015-12-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var enddate= DateTime.ParseExact("2015-12-07", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var result = (from ct in table
              where ct.IsWaiting && (ct.FromDate >= startdate && ct.ToDate <= enddate)
              select ct).ToList();
```